# how to build jar with 2 main classes and dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jar

This is a spring core project with maven. To achieve certain goals i created **two main classes in this project**. Maven is used here because few external jars are needed for this project. Implementation is completed.

What is the problem?
i need a single jar file that enables me to run two different main classes via command prompt.
The external libraries should be bundled with the jar.

i don't need two separate runnable jar for triggering 2 main classes individually. 

Things used for dev are
Java 1.7
Spring core 4.2.2
Maven 3.3.9
Eclipse mars

**Updated:**

i ran below command but i get error which says unable to find the beans.xml.
beans.xml is in the resources folder inside jar

java -cp Batch_toc_browsing.jar;aa11_lib/* com.base.LaunchTocUpdate

```
D:\temp\toc_browsing batch>java -cp Batch_toc_browsing.jar;aa11_lib/* com.base.LaunchTocUpdate
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.base.TreeBuilder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [
Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129
)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.base.TreeBuilder.process(TreeBuilder.java:20)
        at com.base.LaunchTocUpdate.main(LaunchTocUpdate.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: You should at least post the code that is raising the Exception

Comment: in my main post i didnot say that i'm getting an exception. i was asking for approach to build a jar with dependences. i already mentioned its a spring core so its obvious that the project has dependencies and propery files

Comment: i have added exception log incase if you care to look into it.

Comment: i said its a spring core project. isn't it obvious it has a beans.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the answer i wanted but this is one possible way to make use of jar to run the app developed with spring core.

i created a runnable jar but got the exception (which i've mentioned in the question). Its due to the inability of the program to find the beans.xml that exists in the project because somehow what is placed under resources doesn't get placed into classpath, i haven't faced this issue in spring web projects.
**What triggered the problem?**
i had all configs(beans.xml) and properties in the **src/main/resources** folder along with other property files. none of them were detected by the program.
**Solution**
i moved all the config files and property files to **src/main/java**. Things started working.

And this is not the exact solution i wanted as i made this work by creating 2 runnable jars. i will update the post once i get the output of what i initially requested in my question.

Thanks